# ionic | duplicate symbols error when having cordova-plugin-firebase and cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics installed

Tags: firebase, ionic3, cordova-plugins, firebase-analytics, duplicate-symbol

I have `cordova-plugin-firebase`(1.1.3) and `cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics`(1.0.0) installed in my ionic project. But when I build, I get duplicate symbols error in Xcode like below:

```
ld:110 duplicate symbols for archetecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I had both plugins installed before and they both worked well. I need to use the crashlytics feature so I updated **cordova-plugin-firebase** to the newest version(1.1.3), but then I get this message on firebase console:

> To see this data, make sure your app is using the Firebase Analytics
>   SDK and the latest version of Crashlytics.

So I updated **cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics** too(before I was using 0.11.0) and then the message on firebase console disapeared(but build failed), and now I'm getting duplicate symbols error. But if I remove analytics plugin, I get `library not found for -lFirebaseCore` error.

How can I remove duplicate symbols error?

Answer (score 0):

I found out both plugins added firebase.core framework to my project, and that's why I was getting duplicate symbols error.

I removed cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics from package.json and config.xml, and THEN ran `npm install`, it stopped giving me a `library not found for -lFirebaseCore error`.

But now the version 1.1.3 of cordova-plugin-firebase is now deprecated because it had some problems implementing firebase features. I'm currently using cordova-plugin-firebase V2.0.1 and analytics is working just as I expected.